# How add spaces between Slick carousel item

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, slick.js

I want to add space between two slick carousel items, but not want the space with padding, because it's reducing my element size(and I don't want that).

[image]

```js
    $('.single-item').slick({
        initialSlide: 3,
        infinite: false
    });
```

```css
.slick-slider {
    margin:0 -15px;
}
.slick-slide {
    padding:10px;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:gray;">
            <div class="slider single-item" style="background:yellow">
                <div>1</div>
                <div>2</div>
                <div>3</div>
                <div>4</div>
                <div>5</div>
                <div>6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Somehow I am getting space from both side, I am trying to remove that.

Comment: You need to add or remove space from both ends.

Comment: Did you get the solution to this later? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, I have found the solution for dis issue.

- Create **one slider box with extra width** from both side( Which we can use to add item space from both sides ).
- Create **Inner Item Content** with proper width & margin from both sides( This should be your actual wrapper size )
- Done

Answer (score 172):

```
  /* the slides */
  .slick-slide {
      margin: 0 27px;
  }

  /* the parent */
  .slick-list {
      margin: 0 -27px;
  }
```

This problem reported as issue (#582) on plugin's github, btw this solution mentioned there too, (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/582)

Comment: This solution is great and will work. (btw this solution is mentioned in plugin's github profile too, refer to https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/582)

Comment: I needed to place a `overflow: hidden` on the container of the slider to prevent an overflow because of the margin.

Answer (score 31):

The slick-slide has inner wrapping div which you can use to create spacing between slides without breaking the design:

```
.slick-list {margin: 0 -5px;}
.slick-slide>div {padding: 0 5px;}
```

Comment: It works but slides are visible outside of the slider during the animation.

Comment: Added your suggestion using React Slick and Styled Components and it worked.

Answer (score 16):

Since the latest versions you can simply add a `margin` to your slides:

```
.slick-slide {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

There's no need for any kind of negative margins, since slick's calculation is based on the elements `outerHeight`.

Comment: Can you confirm from which version onwards this is the case?

Comment: It works but it also add 20px margin on right and left of slider and that is not really nice.

Answer (score 14):

@Dishan TD's answer works nice, but I'm getting better results using only margin-left.

And to make this clearer to everyone else, you have to pay attention to the both opposite numbers: 27 and -27

```
  /* the slides */
  .slick-slide {
    margin-left:27px;
  }

  /* the parent */
  .slick-list {
    margin-left:-27px;
  }
```

Comment: I needed to place a `overflow: hidden` on the container of the slider to prevent an overflow because of the margin.

Answer (score 9):

An improvement based on the post by Dishan TD (which removes the vertical margin as well):

```
  .slick-slide{
    margin-left:  15px;
    margin-right:  15px;
  }

  .slick-list {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

Note: the pointer-events was necessary in my case, to be able to click on the left arrow.

Answer (score 7):

simply add padding on to the slick-side class will do

```
.slick-slider .slick-slide {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, the `gap` property for flexbox has pretty decent support: https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap

So you can use this:

```css
.slick-track {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
}
```

It'll add space only between elements.

Answer (score 4):

Just fix css:

```
/* the slides */
.slick-slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* the parent */
.slick-list {
    margin: 0 -9px;
}
/* item */  
.item{
    padding: 0 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of pseudo classes removed margins from first and last child, and used [adaptive height](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) true in the script. Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/363ph8q8/7/)

One more [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/363ph8q8/8/)

```
 $('.single-item').slick({
        initialSlide: 3,
        infinite: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true
    });
```

Comment: i have check both of your fiddles, when i am changing to next item it is showing space for first & second . Actually i am trying to remove that space(margin space) on viewable area and use full width of viewable part to single item

Comment: This is the correct answer. Adaptive width and height helped fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For example:
Add this data-attr to your primary slick div: data-space="7"

```
                    $('[data-space]').each(function () {
                        var $this = $(this),
                            $space = $this.attr('data-space');

                        $('.slick-slide').css({
                            marginLeft: $space + 'px',
                            marginRight: $space + 'px'
                        });

                        $('.slick-list').css({
                            marginLeft: -$space + 'px',
                            marginRight: -$space/2 + 'px'
                        })
                    });
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution for changing the space dynamically. I have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
centerPadding: '0'
```

Slider settings will look like:

```
$('.phase-slider-one').slick({
     centerMode: true,
     centerPadding: '0',
     responsive: [{breakpoint: 1024,},{breakpoint: 600,},{breakpoint: 480,}]
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pseudo classes like :first-child & :last-child to remove extra padding from first & last child.

Inspect the generated code of slick slider & try to remove padding on that.

Hope, it'll help!!!

Comment: i have already tried that but it will affect the next items on scroll

Comment: This will not work if you have set 'inifite' option to true

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bigger space between the slides + not to decrease the slide's width, it means you'll have to show less slides. In such case just add a setting to show less slides

```
    $('.single-item').slick({
      initialSlide: 3,
      infinite: false,
      slidesToShow: 3
    });
```

Another option is to define a slide's width by css without setting to amount of slides to show.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works with the latest version of react-slick:

```
  .slick-list {
    margin: 0 -7px !important;
  }
  
  .slick-slide > div {
    padding: 0 7px !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.slick-slide {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.slick-list {
  margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

**screen screen**
data-sm, data-md, data-lg, data-xl, data-xxl and for default screen size data-default

To space between items use space=10, Here 10 is size in "em"

**eg**: I have setting space from small to medium screen 2, and from large to extra large screen I am setting space 5 data-default="[space=2]" data-xl="[space=5]"

**Note**: data-default="[space=1]" these attribute should be set in "your-slick-slider-class" only

*Javascript code*

```
function slickSpacing(space, self){
    self.find('.slick-slide').css({
        marginLeft: space + 'em',
        marginRight: space + 'em'
    });
    self.find('.slick-list').css({
        marginLeft: -space + 'em',
        marginRight: -space/2 + 'em'
    });
}
function slickSlider(){
    $('.slick-slider').each(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        // var screenSize = String(self.attr('data-md')).match(/screen=([0-9]+)/);
        var spaceDefaultSize = String(self.attr('data-default')).match(/space=([0-9]+)/);
        var spaceSmSize = String(self.attr('data-sm')).match(/space=([0-9]+)/);
        var spaceMdSize = String(self.attr('data-md')).match(/space=([0-9]+)/);
        var spaceLgSize = String(self.attr('data-lg')).match(/space=([0-9]+)/);
        var spaceXlSize = String(self.attr('data-xl')).match(/space=([0-9]+)/);
        var spaceXxlSize = String(self.attr('data-xxl')).match(/space=([0-9]+)/);
        if(String(spaceDefaultSize) !== "null"){
            if($(window).innerWidth() >= 0){
                slickSpacing(spaceDefaultSize[1], self)
            }
        }
        if(String(spaceSmSize) !== "null"){
            if($(window).innerWidth() >= 576){
                slickSpacing(spaceSmSize[1], self)
            }
        }
        if(String(spaceMdSize) !== "null"){
            if($(window).innerWidth() >= 768){
                slickSpacing(spaceMdSize[1], self)
            }
        }
        if(String(spaceLgSize) !== "null"){
            if($(window).innerWidth() >= 992){
                slickSpacing(spaceLgSize[1], self)
            }
        }
        if(String(spaceXlSize) !== "null"){
            if($(window).innerWidth() >= 1200){
                slickSpacing(spaceXlSize[1], self)
            }
        }
        if(String(spaceXxlSize) !== "null"){
            if($(window).innerWidth() >= 1400){
                slickSpacing(spaceXxlSize[1], self)
            }
        }
    });
}
$(window).on('resize load', function(){
    slickSlider();
});
```

*HTML Code*

```
<div class="service-slider overflow-hidden" data-default="[space=1]" data-xl="[space=5]">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fake it by adding a border to the slide items. Not by overriding Slick Slider styles, but by adding the border to the elements that you created that will get converted to the slider. Something like this:

```
.my-slide-element {
    &:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
        border-left: 2px solid white;
        border-right: 2px solid white;
    }

    &:first-child {
        border-right: 4px solid white;
    }

    &:last-child {
        border-left: 4px solid white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, this one help me.

```
 .slick-slide {
    margin-left: 5px!important;
    margin-right: 5px!important;
}
.slick-slider {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
```