# slider with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm using the `slick-carousels` project because I'd like to create some kind of slider that is able to show different images in a row.

So what I'd like to get is something similar to this:

[image]

> So the carousel includes a bunch of images where 4 of them are shown at the same time while the images are centered (top & bottom got the same values).

But what I get using my code looks exact like this - what a mess:

[image: image2]

```js
$(document)
  .ready(function() {
    $('.carousel')
      .slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '60px',
        slidesToShow: 4,
        dots: false,
        prevArrow: false,
        nextArrow: false,
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 3
          }
        }]
      });
  });
```

```css
.carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel_slide {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.slick-slide {
  float: left;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}

#card {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>


<div id="card">

  <div class="carousel" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
    <div class="" style="slide">
      <img style="margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b290b.png">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_slide">
      <img style="margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b290b.png">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_slide">
      <img style="margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b290b.png">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_slide">
      <img style="margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b290b.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Edit:**

[image: img]

How to edit my code to achieve the expected result? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Should your slidesToShow property be 4?

Comment: Yup, just a typo. @Observer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the reason was, but I added the class `carousel_slide` to the first `div` after `#card` and got rid of `style='slide'` and I got it to work. Note that when you run this snippet, you'll only see 3 items at a time and not 4. That's because in your code you set the item count to 3 at a breakpoint of 768. So if you still want 4 just change that number.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/4687/

```js
$('.carousel')
  .slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 4,
  dots: false,
  prevArrow: false,
  nextArrow: false,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 768,
    settings: {
      arrows: false,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '40px',
      slidesToShow: 3
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
#card {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 30%;
}

.carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel_slide {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.slick-slide {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="card">
  <div class="carousel" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
    <div class="carousel_slide">
      <img style="margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b290b.png">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_slide">
      <img style="margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b290b.png">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_slide">
      <img style="margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b290b.png">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_slide">
      <img style="margin: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%" src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b585b2edbce24c47b290b.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: **Looks like a good solution** - thanks so much. But would you be so kind to edit your code so that the images are centered but not completely filling up the box (so that they get smaller)? (Like in the image of my question)

Comment: @tempi You mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/4765/

Comment: @tempi So you want only 3 to display and some padding on the top and bottom of the gray box? https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/4890/ I'm just trying to make sure I get what you're asking for.

Comment: Looks pretty good but with your solution I am not able to scale (change the height) of the container box. --> Changing it's height should lead to a alignment of the images. Would you be so kind to add this? :)

Comment: @tempi What do you mean by "should lead to an alignment of the images. Do you want to change the height of the `#card` container?

Comment: Yes and the images should be still in the middle after the height change!

Comment: @tempi Ok so here's what I would do. I would add a clearing element to the container that the div's are floated inside. Then you can ditch the height of the container and use padding. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/5481/

Answer (score 0):

Set both of the slidesToShow's to 4. There are two of them in your code.
Then set negative left margin on .slick-list. https://jsfiddle.net/md9jovwy/9/

```
.slick-slide {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.slick-list{
margin-left: -2%;
}
```

[How add spaces between Slick carousel item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999076/how-add-spaces-between-slick-carousel-item)