# Lower margins (or more item width) between slide items

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm struggling to achieve this, what I want is to the space between the items to be lower, I don't understand why each one is so tiny, I just need a eg. 10px margin between each, or 32% width each.

I already searched (https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/582, [How add spaces between Slick carousel item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999076/how-add-spaces-between-slick-carousel-item)), but none of them resolved my problem.

```js
$('.slick-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  dots: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class='slick-slider text-center'>
    <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>29 JAN 18</small>
      <h6>1</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>02 FEB 18</small>
      <h6>2</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>10 FEB 18</small>
      <h6>3</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>29 JAN 18</small>
      <h6>4</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>02 FEB 18</small>
      <h6>5</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>10 FEB 18</small>
      <h6>6</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work

```js
$('.slick-main').slick({
  arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 3,
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplaySpeed:2500,
    speed: 500,
});
```

```css
.inner-item{
  background: orange;
}
.item {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class='slick-main text-center'>
   <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>29 JAN 18</small>
      <h6>1</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>02 FEB 18</small>
      <h6>2</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>10 FEB 18</small>
      <h6>3</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>29 JAN 18</small>
      <h6>4</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>02 FEB 18</small>
      <h6>5</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slick-slider item">
    <div class="inner-item text-left">
      <small>10 FEB 18</small>
      <h6>6</h6>
      <a href="#">know more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/webdevkumar/jwcsyuhd/1/)